# Show a MessageBox when clicking Menu doesn't appear on screen

Tags: c++, menu, window, messagebox

I've just made a simple C++ Window and added a menu, but when I click on the menu, specifally "About" i want to show a simply MessageBox but I can't - because it doesn't show.

```
LPCWSTR App_Name = TEXT("TestApp");
LPCWSTR App_Title = TEXT("TestTitle");

const int windowWidth = 480;
const int windowHeight = 480;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH );
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = App_Name;
    wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(MNU_MAINMENU);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    RegisterClass(&wc); 

    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rc);

    long screenWidth = rc.right;
    long screenHeight = rc.bottom;

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow
    (
        App_Name,
        App_Title,
        WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2), (screenHeight / 2)-(windowHeight/2),
        windowWidth, windowHeight,
        NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL
    );


    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow );
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg;

    while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

and the MessageBox...:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{   
        switch( message )
        {

        case WM_COMMAND:
            id = LOWORD(wparam);
            event = LOWORD(wparam);
            switch(id)
            {
                case MNU_HELP_ABOUT:
                MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("TEXT"), TEXT("TITLE"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                break;
            }
        break;

        }
}
```

Menu works, cause I've added a Quit and such so I know it responds to the clicks on the menu but when I click the About button you hear the popup sound but there's no MessageBox showing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, somehow. Problem was because I haven't done anything in WM_CREATE, or that that "nothing" was on the form - White background, or something. As soon as I started adding controls (buttons) to the Window it suddenly appeared where it didn't before. Just weird...

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to MessageBox is the hWnd of the parent. Note that the MessageBox call is synchronous, so control won't return to your WndProc until the user has clicked the OK button. (Therefore your window is unresponsive.) You haven't supplied the parent hWnd though, so it is possible that the message box has been created *beneath* your window.

Try passing hwnd as the first MessageBox parameter and see if that helps.

Comment: Already tried that, same results. Had it as default, just my last test I didn't have it. So...

Comment: OK. Run SpyXX (which I assume still exists) and see if you can find the message box in the list of windows.

Comment: Oh, and output a log message or something similar to verify that the call to MessageBox is actually made.

Comment: There's nothing in the output tab when I debug?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, try adding a call to OutputDebugString just before the MessageBox call.

Comment: But that just outputs a string that I provide into the debugger output.

Comment: Quite, which would show that your code is being called, which is good to know.

Comment: Yes, as I've said you can see the Window going out of focus and sometime you hear a sound. Probably when it's there but not there. I've added the rest of my code above. Pretty much all of it, exept other calls to other menus.

Comment: Have a look in Spy++ to see whether the message box has been created, and where it is.

Comment: Spy++ looks like spyware :P Any other suggestions on how to proceed? Can't be the first time someone tried to show a MessageBox after a menuclick.

Comment: Ok. Figured that. In which environment, Visual Studio, Codeblocks?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010, started with a Win32 project.